# search form closes after clicking in form field

Tags: php, wordpress, search-form

Hi dear programming and PHP geniuses,

I'm new to php and effed up a search form on my Wordpress shop page (wich isn't public yet). After searching for the error for days I still have no clue where the error might be. I installed SublimeText + SublimeLinter to find a syntax error, but apparently there is none ...

The search form closes as soon as I try to type something in (as soon as I click in it).

I use the Mr. Tailor Theme: http://themeforest.net/item/mr-tailor-responsive-woocommerce-theme/full_screen_preview/7292110

So, here is the code (it's quite long and I'm not sure if this alone helps, so please let me know if I have to add anything):

```
<?php global $woocommerce, $mr_tailor_theme_options; ?>

                    <footer id="site-footer" role="contentinfo">



<div id="own_footer">
            <img src="../../image_assets/logo_footer.png" alt="Logo">

            <br><br><br>
            <p>Folgen Sie uns auf: </p>

            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/fuchsundfeder/" target="_blank"><img                 src="../../image_assets/instagram_footer.png" alt="Logo" > </a>

            <img src="../../image_assets/facebook_footer.png" alt="Logo" >

            <a href="https://de.pinterest.com/fuchsundfeder/" target="_blank"><img src="../../image_assets/pinterest_footer.png" alt="Logo" > </a>


            <br><br><br>

            </div>



            <br><br>

            <p id="newsletter_copy">
                NEWSLETTER
                <br><br>

                Sie haben Interesse an unserem Newsletter und möchten regelmäßig über neue  Produkte, 
                Sonderangebote und andere tolle Sachen informiert werden? Dann registrieren Sie sich für unseren                    
                Newsletter.
            </p>





                    <div id="footer_eingabefeld"> 
                    <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'footer-widget-area' ) ) : ?>

                        <div class="trigger-footer-widget-area">
                                <span class="trigger-footer-widget-icon"></span>
                            </div>

                        <div class="site-footer-widget-area">
                            <div class="row">
                                <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'footer-widget-area' ); ?>




                            </div><!-- .row -->
                    </div><!-- .site-footer-widget-area -->





<?php endif; ?>


<div id="footer_links">


<li><a href="http://fuchsundfeder.com/pages/about-us">Über Fuchs und Feder</a></li>
<li><a href="http://fuchsundfeder.com/contact">Kontakt</a></li>
<li><a href="http://fuchsundfeder.com/pages/faqs">FAQ</a></li>
<li><a href="http://fuchsundfeder.com/impressum">Impressum</a></li>
<li><a href="http://fuchsundfeder.com/mein-konto">Mein Konto</a></li>


</div>             





<div class="site-footer-copyright-area">

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="medium-4 columns">  
                                    <div class="payment_methods">

                                        <?php
                                        if ( (isset($mr_tailor_theme_options['credit_card_icons']['url'])) && (trim($mr_tailor_theme_options['credit_card_icons']['url']) != "" ) ) {
                                            if (is_ssl()) {
                                                $credit_card_icons = str_replace("http://", "https://", $mr_tailor_theme_options['credit_card_icons']['url']);      
                                            } else {
                                                $credit_card_icons = $mr_tailor_theme_options['credit_card_icons']['url'];
                                            }
                                        ?>

                                        <img src="<?php echo $credit_card_icons; ?>" alt="<?php _e( 'Payment methods', 'mr_tailor' )?>" />

                                        <?php } ?>  

                                    </div><!-- .payment_methods -->
                                </div><!-- .large-4 .columns -->

                                <div class="medium-8 columns">
                                    <div class="copyright_text">
                                        <?php if ( (isset($mr_tailor_theme_options['footer_copyright_text'])) && (trim($mr_tailor_theme_options['footer_copyright_text']) != "" ) ) { ?>
                                            <?php _e( $mr_tailor_theme_options['footer_copyright_text'], 'mr_tailor' ); ?>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                    </div><!-- .copyright_text -->  
                                </div><!-- .large-8 .columns -->            
                            </div><!-- .row --> 
                        </div><!-- .site-footer-copyright-area -->

                    </footer>


                </div><!-- #page -->

            </div><!-- /st-content -->
        </div><!-- /st-pusher -->










        <nav class="st-menu slide-from-left">
            <div class="nano">
                <div class="nano-content">
                    <div id="mobiles-menu-offcanvas" class="offcanvas-left-content">

                        <nav id="mobile-main-navigation" class="mobile-navigation" role="navigation">
                        <?php 
                            wp_nav_menu(array(
                                'theme_location'  => 'main-navigation',
                                'fallback_cb'     => false,
                                'container'       => false,
                                'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s">%3$s</ul>',
                            ));
                        ?>
                        </nav>

                        <?php 

                        $theme_locations  = get_nav_menu_locations();
                        if (isset($theme_locations['top-bar-navigation'])) {
                            $menu_obj = get_term($theme_locations['top-bar-navigation'], 'nav_menu');
                        }

                        if ( (isset($menu_obj->count) && ($menu_obj->count > 0)) || (is_user_logged_in()) ) {
                        ?>

                            <nav id="mobile-top-bar-navigation" class="mobile-navigation" role="navigation">
                            <?php 
                                wp_nav_menu(array(
                                    'theme_location'  => 'top-bar-navigation',
                                    'fallback_cb'     => false,
                                    'container'       => false,
                                    'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s">%3$s</ul>',
                                ));
                            ?>

                            <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>
                                <ul><li><a href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/?<?php echo get_option('woocommerce_logout_endpoint'); ?>=true" class="logout_link"><?php _e('Logout', 'mr_tailor'); ?></a></li></ul>
                            <?php } ?>
                            </nav>

                        <?php } ?>

                        <div class="language-and-currency-offcanvas hide-for-large-up">

                            <?php if (function_exists('icl_get_languages')) { ?>

                                <?php $additional_languages = icl_get_languages('skip_missing=N&orderby=KEY&order=DIR&link_empty_to=str'); ?>

                                <select class="topbar-language-switcher">
                                    <option><?php echo ICL_LANGUAGE_NAME; ?></option>
                                    <?php

                                    if (count($additional_languages) > 1) {
                                        foreach($additional_languages as $additional_language){
                                          if(!$additional_language['active']) $langs[] = '<option value="'.$additional_language['url'].'">'.$additional_language['native_name'].'</option>';
                                        }
                                        echo join(', ', $langs);
                                    }

                                    ?>
                                </select>

                            <?php } ?>

                            <?php if (class_exists('woocommerce_wpml')) { ?>
                                <?php echo(do_shortcode('[currency_switcher]')); ?>
                            <?php } ?>

                        </div>









                        <div class="mobile-socials">
                            <div class="site-social-icons">
                                <ul class="//animated //flipY">
                                    <?php if ( (isset($mr_tailor_theme_options['facebook_link'])) && (trim($mr_tailor_theme_options['facebook_link']) != "" ) ) { ?><li class="site-social-icons-facebook"><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $mr_tailor_theme_options['facebook_link']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i><span>Facebook</span></a></li><?php } ?>
                                    <?php if ( (isset($mr_tailor_theme_options['twitter_link'])) && (trim($mr_tailor_theme_options['twitter_link']) != "" ) ) { ?><li class="site-social-icons-twitter"><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $mr_tailor_theme_options['twitter_link']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i><span>Twitter</span></a></li><?php } ?>
                                    <?php if ( (isset($mr_tailor_theme_options['pinterest_link'])) && (trim($mr_tailor_theme_options['pinterest_link']) != "" ) ) { ?><li class="site-social-icons-pinterest"><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $mr_tailor_theme_options['pinterest_link']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i><span>Pinterest</span></a></li><?php } ?>
                                    <?php if ( (isset($mr_tailor_theme_options['linkedin_link'])) && (trim($mr_tailor_theme_options['linkedin_link']) != "" ) ) { ?><li class="site-social-icons-linkedin"><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $mr_tailor_theme_options['linkedin_link']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i><span>LinkedIn</span></a></li><?php } ?>
                                    <?php if ( (isset($mr_tailor_theme_options['googleplus_link'])) && (trim($mr_tailor_theme_options['googleplus_link']) != "" ) ) { ?><li class="site-social-icons-googleplus"><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $mr_tailor_theme_options['googleplus_link']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i><span>Google+</span></a></li><?php } ?>
                                    <?php if ( (isset($mr_tailor_theme_options['rss_link'])) && (trim($mr_tailor_theme_options['rss_link']) != "" ) ) { ?><li class="site-social-icons-rss"><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $mr_tailor_theme_options['rss_link']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-rss"></i><span>RSS</span></a></li><?php } ?>
                                    <?php if ( (isset($mr_tailor_theme_options['tumblr_link'])) && (trim($mr_tailor_theme_options['tumblr_link']) != "" ) ) { ?><li class="site-social-icons-tumblr"><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $mr_tailor_theme_options['tumblr_link']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-tumblr"></i><span>Tumblr</span></a></li><?php } ?>
                                    <?php if ( (isset($mr_tailor_theme_options['instagram_link'])) && (trim($mr_tailor_theme_options['instagram_link']) != "" ) ) { ?><li class="site-social-icons-instagram"><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $mr_tailor_theme_options['instagram_link']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i><span>Instagram</span></a></li><?php } ?>
                                    <?php if ( (isset($mr_tailor_theme_options['youtube_link'])) && (trim($mr_tailor_theme_options['youtube_link']) != "" ) ) { ?><li class="site-social-icons-youtube"><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $mr_tailor_theme_options['youtube_link']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i><span>Youtube</span></a></li><?php } ?>
                                    <?php if ( (isset($mr_tailor_theme_options['vimeo_link'])) && (trim($mr_tailor_theme_options['vimeo_link']) != "" ) ) { ?><li class="site-social-icons-vimeo"><a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $mr_tailor_theme_options['vimeo_link']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-vimeo-square"></i><span>Vimeo</span></a></li><?php } ?>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div id="filters-offcanvas" class="offcanvas-left-content wpb_widgetised_column">
                        <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'catalog-widget-area' ) ) : ?>
                            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'catalog-widget-area' ); ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <nav class="st-menu slide-from-right">
            <div class="nano">
                <div class="nano-content">
                    <div id="minicart-offcanvas" class="offcanvas-right-content"><?php if ( class_exists( 'WC_Widget_Cart' ) ) { the_widget( 'mr_tailor_WC_Widget_Cart' ); } ?></div>
                    <div id="wishlist-offcanvas" class="offcanvas-right-content"><div class="widget"></div></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>




    </div><!-- /st-container -->

    <!-- ******************************************************************** -->
    <!-- * Custom Footer JavaScript Code ************************************ -->
    <!-- ******************************************************************** -->

    <?php if ( (isset($mr_tailor_theme_options['footer_js'])) && ($mr_tailor_theme_options['footer_js'] != "") ) : ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            <?php echo $mr_tailor_theme_options['footer_js']; ?>
        </script>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ( (isset($mr_tailor_theme_options['sticky_header'])) && (trim($mr_tailor_theme_options['sticky_header']) == "1" ) ) : ?>


    <!-- ******************************************************************** -->
    <!-- * Sticky Header **************************************************** -->
    <!-- ******************************************************************** -->

    <div class="site-header-sticky">
        <div class="row">       
        <div class="large-12 columns">
            <div class="site-header-sticky-inner">
                <div class="site-branding">

                    <?php
                    if ( (isset($mr_tailor_theme_options['site_logo']['url'])) && (trim($mr_tailor_theme_options['site_logo']['url']) != "" ) ) {
                        if (is_ssl()) {
                            $site_logo = str_replace("http://", "https://", $mr_tailor_theme_options['site_logo']['url']);      
                        } else {
                            $site_logo = $mr_tailor_theme_options['site_logo']['url'];
                        }
                    ?>



                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><img class="site-logo" src="<?php echo $site_logo; ?>" title="<?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?>" /></a>

                    <?php } else { ?>

                        <div class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></div>

                    <?php } ?>

                </div><!-- .site-branding -->

                <?php
                if ( (isset($mr_tailor_theme_options['site_logo_retina']['url'])) && (trim($mr_tailor_theme_options['site_logo_retina']['url']) != "" ) ) {
                ?>
                <script>
                //<![CDATA[

                    // Set pixelRatio to 1 if the browser doesn't offer it up.
                    var pixelRatio = !!window.devicePixelRatio ? window.devicePixelRatio : 1;

                    logo_image = new Image();

                    jQuery(window).load(function(){

                        if (pixelRatio > 1) {
                            jQuery('.site-logo').each(function() {

                                var logo_image_width = jQuery(this).width();
                                var logo_image_height = jQuery(this).height();

                                jQuery(this).css("width", logo_image_width);
                                jQuery(this).css("height", logo_image_height);

                                jQuery(this).attr('src', '<?php echo $mr_tailor_theme_options['site_logo_retina']['url'] ?>');
                            });
                        };

                    });

                //]]>
                </script>
                <?php } ?>

                <div id="site-menu">

                    <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">                    
                        <?php 
                            wp_nav_menu(array(
                                'theme_location'  => 'main-navigation',
                                'fallback_cb'     => false,
                                'container'       => false,
                                'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s">%3$s</ul>',
                            ));
                        ?>           
                    </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->                  

                    <div class="site-tools">
                        <ul>

                            <li class="mobile-menu-button"><a><i class="getbowtied-icon-menu"></i></a></li>

                            <?php if (class_exists('YITH_WCWL')) : ?>
                            <?php if ( (isset($mr_tailor_theme_options['main_header_wishlist'])) && (trim($mr_tailor_theme_options['main_header_wishlist']) == "1" ) ) : ?>
                            <li class="wishlist-button"><a><i class="getbowtied-icon-heart"></i></a><span class="wishlist_items_number"><?php echo yith_wcwl_count_products(); ?></span></li>                           
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>



                            <?php if (class_exists('WooCommerce')) : ?>
                            <?php if ( (isset($mr_tailor_theme_options['main_header_shopping_bag'])) && (trim($mr_tailor_theme_options['main_header_shopping_bag']) == "1" ) ) : ?>
                            <?php if ( (isset($mr_tailor_theme_options['catalog_mode'])) && ($mr_tailor_theme_options['catalog_mode'] == 1) ) : ?>
                            <?php else : ?>
                            <li class="shopping-bag-button" class="right-off-canvas-toggle"><a><i class="getbowtied-icon-shop"></i></a><span class="shopping_bag_items_number"><?php echo $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count; ?></span></li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                            <?php if ( (isset($mr_tailor_theme_options['main_header_search_bar'])) && (trim($mr_tailor_theme_options['main_header_search_bar']) == "1" ) ) : ?>
                            <li class="search-button"><a><i class="getbowtied-icon-search"></i></a></li>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                        </ul>   
                    </div>

                    <div class="site-search">
                        <?php
                        if (class_exists('WooCommerce')) {
                            the_widget( 'WC_Widget_Product_Search', 'title=' );
                        } else {
                            the_widget( 'WP_Widget_Search', 'title=' );
                        }
                        ?>             
                    </div><!-- .site-search -->


                </div><!-- #site-menu -->

                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div><!--.site-header-sticky-inner-->  
        </div><!-- .large-12-->
        </div><!--.row--> 
    </div><!-- .site-header-sticky -->

    <?php endif; ?>



    <!-- ******************************************************************** -->
    <!-- * WP Footer() ****************************************************** -->
    <!-- ******************************************************************** -->

    <div class="login_header">
        <a class="go_home" href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a>
    </div>


<?php wp_footer(); ?>

</body>

</html>
```

Weird thing is also, that this code is from the footer.php, but still it apparently influences the search bar....

I know it's kinda like dynamite fishing, but I just ran out of ideas. So thank you all in advance!

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what you mean by 'the form closes'? Does it literally disappear off the page? Does it submit?

Comment: initially there is just the magnifying-glass icon. if I click on that icon, the form field and "search" button appear. if I click in the form field, it instantly collapses again and is back to it's origin state of just the magnifying glass.

Comment: That does not sound like a backend code issue. It sounds like a frontend issue. Can you provide a link to a working demo(of your site, not the WP template)? Or replicate the issue on jsfiddle?

Comment: Since the website is password protected, I'd rather try to replicate it on fiddle. I let you know if it worked. Thank you so far, for your time!

Comment: Hey, I decided to publish the site for now. Didn't work with fiddle. Here is the link: http://fuchsundfeder.com/
Thx

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing the event targets id but the event target does not have an id set. If you inspect your code, the search input element has no id set.

scripts.js(143):

```
$("body").on('click',function(e) {
    if($(e.target).attr('class') == 'getbowtied-icon-search' 
       || $(e.target).attr('id') == 's') {
            return;
    } else {
        reset_search_toggles()
        $('body').unbind('click');
    }
});
```

If you can not add an id to that element for whatever reason you can also search by its name(I do not advise this, id's are much better).

```
if($(e.target).attr('class') == 'getbowtied-icon-search' 
    || $(e.target).attr('id') == 's'
    || $(e.target).attr('name') == 's') {
```

Comment: Wow, works like a charm. I would have stepped in the dark for years to find that. 
Thank you very much for your quick help!